# Trying to assert a hidden value is present in ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

I'm trying to assert that a label changes when a button with a unique id is clicked, but not getting very very far.  The application I'm using assigns an id to a row which has linked functions and labels, so far i can use the row id to amend, delete and update a status through a button but cannot assert a label change.

The code I'm using to extract the id is;

```
@@grabelement = $browser.hidden(:name, "contentHeadingID")
@@id = @@grabelement.value
puts @@id
```

I'm then using the code below to click a button that updates a displayed status label

```
form_element = $browser.hidden(:name => 'contentHeadingID', :value => "#{@@id}").parent
form_element.button(:value => 'Change').click
```

the status label is wrapped in to the same code structure

```
<input type="submit" name="publish" value="Change" class="btn btn-mini btn-secondary" style="float:right">
<input type="hidden" name="contentHeadingID" id="8" value="8">
<input type="hidden" name="published" id="Yes" value="Yes">
```

on click of change the id and value are updated to No and a label is change from Unpublished to Published (and vice versa)

the code I've tried is;

```
if
form_element = $browser.hidden(:id => 'Yes', :value => "#{@@id}").parent
form_element.id(:value => 'Yes') == true
puts "Published status updated"
else
puts "failed"
end
```

any help would be great

Comment: Which one are you referring to as the "label"? I do not see any label elements. Given that you said the label changes between Unpublished/Published, are you saying you are trying to assert the name attribute of the hidden element `<input type="hidden" name="published" id="Yes" value="Yes">`?

Comment: Hi Justin, i was not as clear as I though. But yes, the item with the name published. It is either id & value = 'yes' or 'no'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to check if the form_element includes a hidden element with id "No", value "No" and name "Published". You could create a locator that matches that specific element and check if it exists:

```
form_element = $browser.hidden(:id => 'Yes', :value => "#{@@id}").parent
if form_element.hidden(:id => 'No', :value => 'No', :name => 'Published').exists?
  puts "Published status updated"
else
  puts "failed"
end
```

Note that you have to use `.exists?` instead of `present?` or `visible?` since hidden elements will never be visable.